# How to retrieve an image from Amazon S3 and send it from back-end to front-end?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

How can I retrieve an image from Amazon S3, and send the binary data to the front-end to be rendered? I'm trying to access a private image that has the ACL set to "private". Basically the Image should be returned from the getObject function, however, I'm stuck on what properties I need to retrieve and how to properly send the binary image to the front-end. There is a property called Body that is a Binary Format.

````
return this.s3Client.getObject({
   Bucket: SPACES_BUCKET_NAME,
   Key: key,
});```
````

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to get a Signed URL

eg:

```
return this.s3Client.getSignedUrl("getObject", {
    Bucket: SPACES_BUCKET_NAME,
    Key: key,
    Expires: expires || 900, // S3 default is 900 seconds (15 minutes)
  });
```